# Как спросить на авито информацию о том какое продвижение применили к объявлению?

Tags: python, scrapy

Мне нужно спросить с авито информацию о объявлении на python. Нужно понять какая услуга продвижения была применена и сколько просмотров за сутки вышло у конкурентов.

Если зайти на [avito.ru](https://www.avito.ru/moskva/chasy_i_ukrasheniya/chasy/smart-ASgBAgICAkTQAYYGhNgR_paHAw?cd=1&q=apple+watch) версия сайта для компьютера, то под каждым объявлением возле времени публикации есть стрелочка и если на неё навести мышку, то всплывает окошка с информацией о том какая услуга применяется.
[image: Стрелочка]
[image: информация]

Я использую библиотеку scrapy. Я не могу понять как получить данные которые появляются когда наводишь курсор мыши на стрелку.

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно получить информацию о том какая услуга продвижения применяется?